# How to convert plain object to nested sub object using Linq to SQL C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am working an application where I am receiving a plain list from database which I need to convert into the following JSON object. Here is what I have tried so far. I am not willing use nested **foreach** loops.

> JSON

```
{
  "Location": [
    {
      "LocationID": "123456",
      "DBSIdentifier": "EQUIP",
      "DBSVersion": "3221",
      "InterfaceVersion": "2.0",
      "LanguageCode": "EN",
      "CounterSale": [
        {
          "InvoiceNumber": "941041",
          "CreationTimestamp": "2018-04-02T07:03:18",
          "InvoiceTimestamp": "2018-04-02T07:03:18",
          "Part": [
            {
              "PartNumber": "AT194969",
              "Quantity": "1.00",
              "Description": "KEY",
              "DeerePart": "true",
              "MiscellaneousPart": "false",
              "PartsPerPackage": "1",
              "StockingLogicCode": "12A",
              "UnitofMeasure": "",
              "Warehouse": "D-1",
              "HistorySale": "N",
              "OnlineOrder": "",
              "PickListID": ""
            }
          ]
        }]
        }]
    }
```

> CODE

```
string connectionString = "data source=localhost;initial catalog=ASPENDV;integrated security=true;";
var result = new List<DataClass>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    result = connection.Query<DataClass>("sp_TestData", commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}


#region [@ ##### ]


var obj = result.GroupBy(x => x.LocationId);

var root = obj.Select(x => new Root()
{
    Location = x.Select(l => new Location()
    {
        LocationID = l.LocationId,
        DBSIdentifier = l.DBSIdentifier,
        CounterSale = x.GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceNumber).Select(c => new CounterSale()
        {
            InvoiceNumber = l.InvoiceNumber,
            CreationTimestamp = l.CreationTimestamp,
            Part = x.Select(p => new Part()
            {
                PartNumber = p.PartNumber,
                Description = p.Description,
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList(),
    }).ToList(),
}); ;

#endregion
```

> MODELS

```
   public class DataClass
        {
            public string? LanguageCode { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; }
            public string? DBSHEADERPARTSK { get; set; }
            public string? DBSIdentifier { get; set; }
            public int DBSVersion { get; set; }
            public string? Description { get; set; }
            public string? InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
            public Nullable<DateTime> InvoiceTimestamp { get; set; }
            public string? PartNumber { get; set; }
            public string? PartSerialNumber { get; set; }
            public int? PartPerPackage { get; set; }
            public int MfgId { get; set; }
            public int LocationId { get; set; }
        }

    public class CounterSale
    {
        public CounterSale()
        {
            this.Part = new List<Part>();
        }
        public string? InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; }
        public DateTime InvoiceTimestamp { get; set; }
        public List<Part> Part { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public Location()
        {
            this.CounterSale = new List<CounterSale>();
        }
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        public string? DBSIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string? DBSVersion { get; set; }
        public string? InterfaceVersion { get; set; }
        public string? LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public List<CounterSale> CounterSale { get; set; }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public string? PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string? Quantity { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Root()
        {
            this.Location = new List<Location>();
        }
        public List<Location> Location { get; set; }
    }
```

My stored procedure returns data which I am binding into DataClass which I need to bind into Root Model as like JSON.

I am not able to bind the result into Root Model how can I do that ?

Comment: You have not asked a question.  Don't imply the question. Ask the question outright.

Comment: I am not able to bind the result into Root Model how can I do that  ?

Comment: Giving it a quick once over, you call `.ToList()` three times at different levels of your query. Are you sure you don't want nested loops? What do you think `.ToList()` does?

Comment: I am aware of it how could I improve this code ?

Comment: why did you convert to json with database side?

Comment: From database I am receiving list of records I don't want to use JSON on database side as it is not supported for earlier versions

Comment: why do you don't use json parse C#?https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/convert-object-to-json-in-csharp

Comment: Bro my query is returning me a plain list of records which I need to convert to complex object as you can see in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest building a nested grouping from the bottom up by first grouping by location & invoice and then grouping again just by location. The resulting structure will similar to your desired structure, and it is then just a matter of traversing the groupings to build out your final nested data structure.

Something like:

```
List<DataClass> result; // No initialization needed here
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    result = connection.Query<DataClass>("sp_TestData", commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}

// Grouping<Key=LocationId, Collection=Grouping<Key={LocationId, InvoiceNumber}, Collection=DataClass>
var nestedGroups = result
    .GroupBy(dat => new {dat.LocationId, dat.InvoiceNumber})
    .GroupBy(invGroup => invGroup.Key.LocationId)
    //??maybe?? .ToList()
    ;

var root = new Root()
{
    Location = nestedGroups.Select(locGroup => new Location()
    {
        LocationID = locGroup.Key,
        DBSIdentifier = locGroup.First().First().DBSIdentifier,
        CounterSale = locGroup.Select(invGroup => new CounterSale()
        {
            InvoiceNumber = invGroup.Key.InvoiceNumber,
            CreationTimestamp = invGroup.First().CreationTimestamp,
            Part = invGroup.Select(dat => new Part()
            {
                PartNumber = dat.PartNumber,
                Description = dat.Description,
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList()
};
```

The `.First()` and `.First().First()` calls are used to reach down into the lowest level to retrieve values not included in the upper level grouping key. You could include `DBSIdentifier` and `CreationTimestamp` in the `.GroupBy(...)` selectors, but that would likely be less efficient than grouping using just the IDs.

See [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZfLcJa) for a demo.

Sample results:

```
{
  "Location": [
    {
      "LocationID": 1,
      "DBSIdentifier": "11",
      "DBSVersion": null,
      "InterfaceVersion": null,
      "LanguageCode": null,
      "CounterSale": [
        {
          "InvoiceNumber": "201",
          "CreationTimestamp": "2023-05-11T03:18:33.9510984+00:00",
          "InvoiceTimestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "Part": [
            {
              "PartNumber": "301",
              "Quantity": null,
              "Description": "A"
            },
            {
              "PartNumber": "302",
              "Quantity": null,
              "Description": "B"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "InvoiceNumber": "202",
          "CreationTimestamp": "2023-05-11T03:18:33.9510984+00:00",
          "InvoiceTimestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "Part": [
            {
              "PartNumber": "303",
              "Quantity": null,
              "Description": "C"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "LocationID": 2,
      "DBSIdentifier": "22",
      "DBSVersion": null,
      "InterfaceVersion": null,
      "LanguageCode": null,
      "CounterSale": [
        {
          "InvoiceNumber": "203",
          "CreationTimestamp": "2023-05-11T03:18:33.9510984+00:00",
          "InvoiceTimestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "Part": [
            {
              "PartNumber": "301",
              "Quantity": null,
              "Description": "A"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```